# Determining differences in test equipment with dimensional reduction

Tags: machine-learning, variance, dimensionality-reduction

We use many copies of test stations to test our RF products, and on a regular basis we need to ensure our test stations are all measuring/behaving the same way.

Each sample or test session has ~1000 measurements that make up the feature set. I have been using scikit learn to apply Linear Discriminant Analysis and then using the coefficients to indicate which features (or test reference) is contributing most to variation between stations.

Is this a valid technique to accurately determine differences between stations with large feature sets, or is there a better technique that I should be looking at?

Thanks!
Scott

Comment: 1000 features in a discriminant analysis feels like a situation primed to guarantee over-fitting to your data. That may or may not be a practical problem in your case.  How confident are you that your 1000 features do not include redundant information? Is the goal to identify "misbehaving" or just differently behaving test stations? Also what labels are you currently feeding the model - each testing station id?

Comment: I would definitely expect highly correlated features in those 1000. Goal is finding which features are behaving differently (support team tells me what is acceptable/unacceptable). The labels are test station IDs (max labels ~5 test stations for a given analysis).